# Got an issue react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin FAILED when I tried to run the app

Tags: javascript, react-native, kotlin, react-native-navigation

Task :react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
w: Java source root points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\bragadeeshvar.gk\OneDrive - ASG Technologies Group
w: Java source root points to a non-existent location: Inc\Desktop\WorkSpace\ReactNative\React-Native-Navigation6\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
C:/Users/bragadeeshvar.gk/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/6786ed219b01aac6d7fac2224360f0ad/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.10.jar (version 1.4)
C:/Users/bragadeeshvar.gk/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0b89a6e271d5397d75101de110d10151/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.20.jar (version 1.5)
C:/Users/bragadeeshvar.gk/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/6f601df8028ce88b89197e8db9061d3b/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.20.jar (version 1.5)
C:/Users/bragadeeshvar.gk/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a47876ccfbe98b22d9c60c8cfded68df/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.20.jar (version 1.5)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
93 actionable tasks: 93 executed
Note: C:\Users\bragadeeshvar.gk\OneDrive - ASG Technologies Group, Inc\Desktop\WorkSpace\ReactNative\React-Native-Navigation6\node_modules@react-native-async-storage\async-storage\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\asyncstorage\AsyncStorageModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\bragadeeshvar.gk\OneDrive - ASG Technologies Group, Inc\Desktop\WorkSpace\ReactNative\React-Native-Navigation6\node_modules@react-native-async-storage\async-storage\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\asyncstorage\AsyncStoragePackage.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
e: C:\Users\bragadeeshvar.gk\OneDrive - ASG Technologies Group, Inc\Desktop\WorkSpace\ReactNative\React-Native-Navigation6\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\ScreenStackHeaderConfig.kt: (376, 23): Unresolved reference: BuildConfig

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin'.

My build.gradle:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20"
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have the same issue did you find a solution?

Comment: I have a similar problem, but nothing to do with react: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74884511/compilekotlin-task-says-java-source-root-points-to-a-non-existent-location-on