# compileKotlin task says "Java source root points to a non-existent location"

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, antlr, gradlew

I'm getting this error when I compile my project on Windows under gradle. This is the first three lines of the error:

```
> Task :core:compileKotlin FAILED
w: Java source root points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\pchol\IdeaProjects\space-empires\core\src\main\generated\com\pcholt\se\OrdersBaseListener.java
w: Java source root points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\pchol\IdeaProjects\space-empires\core\src\main\generated\com\pcholt\se\OrdersLexer.java
```

I've done the usual thing and searched for the string "Java source root points to a non-existent location" and google returns **absolutely nothing**.

**The files exist.** In IntelliJ, I can click on the files, and they come up in the editor. In fact, the IDE doesn't show any errors at all, until you try to run anything. Files appear in explorer.

These files are created by the antlr plugin, with these commands:

```
processResources {
    dependsOn generateGrammarSource
}
generateGrammarSource {
    outputDirectory = file("src/main/generated")
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/kotlin", "src/main/generated"]
        }
    }
}
```

When I **delete** the `C:\Users\pchol\IdeaProjects\space-empires\.gradle` directory, and rebuild the application, I can build it without problems. The error doesn't appear, the `.jar` is generated and runs fine. If I make any subsequent changes to the code, and try again, the error returns.

- Kotlin version 1.7.22
- Jvm version 16
- antlr 4.11.1

```
PS C:\Users\pchol> java --version
java 17.0.2 2022-01-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I have switched off caching in `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.caching=false
```

It's not an IDE problem - on the windows command line I get:
[image: image of the error shown above, but created from gradlew clear jar]

---

### Update `2022 Dec 23`

This is not only a Windows problem. I checked the codebase out on a Linux partition, and I get the same issue:

```
> Task :core:compileKotlin FAILED
w: Java source root points to a non-existent location: /home/ph/IdeaProjects/se/core/src/main/generated/com/pcholt/se/OrdersLexer.java
w: Java source root points to a non-existent location: /home/ph/IdeaProjects/se/core/src/main/generated/com/pcholt/se/OrdersListener.java
```

This also happens on OpenJDK

```
ph@po:~/IdeaProjects/se$ java --version
openjdk 17.0.4 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.4+8-Ubuntu-120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.4+8-Ubuntu-120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip

Comment: It smells to me like a file-system case-sensitivity issue.  Check this carefully

Comment: Thanks @AndrewL - you inspired me to try it out on Linux. Good idea, but looks like a dud! Still same problem.

Comment: OK, next thing that seems unusual is your path to these generated files: "/home/ph/IdeaProjects/se/core/src/main/generated/com/pcholt..." Normally the compiler defaults to looking in places like src/main/java or src/main/kotlin not in src/main/generated

Comment: The generated directory comes from the `generateGrammarSource` task, which takes a grammar and outputs a source directory.  I included that in the source directories list with `srcDirs = ["src/main/kotlin", "src/main/generated"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to specify an explicit relationship between the compilation task and the grammar generation task

build.gradle.kts:

```kotlin
// ...

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    dependsOn(tasks.generateGrammarSource)
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

// ...
```

Comment: I think you might have solved it!